# Getting cyclic error with Terraform while doing Azure app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to register two applications one is a Front End App and the other is a Backend App. I am having corresponding Web Apps for them as well.
I am using Terraform to deploy my apps and all the infrastructure.
But while running TF plan i get the cyclic error. Please find below my code.
Can anyone please help me rectify this

**Code for Web App FE**

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "fe" {
  location            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  tags                = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.tags

  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.default.id
  name                = module.names-web-app-fe.location.app_service.name_unique
  identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }

  auth_settings {
    enabled                       = true
    default_provider              = "AzureActiveDirectory"
    issuer                        = format("https://sts.windows.net/%s/", data.azurerm_client_config.default.tenant_id)
    runtime_version               = "~1"
    token_store_enabled           = true
    unauthenticated_client_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    additional_login_params = {
      "response_type" = "code id_token",
      "resource"      = azuread_application.app-fe.application_id
    }
    active_directory {
      client_id         = azuread_application.app-fe.object_id
      client_secret     = azuread_application_password.fe-app-sp-secret.application_object_id
      allowed_audiences = [format("https://%s.azurewebsites.net", module.names-web-app-fe.location.app_service.name_unique)]
    }
  }

  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    app_command_line         = ""
    default_documents        = []
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    ftps_state               = "Disabled"
    health_check_path        = ""
    http2_enabled            = true
    linux_fx_version         = "STATICSITE|1.0"
    local_mysql_enabled      = false
    managed_pipeline_mode    = "Integrated"
    min_tls_version          = "1.2"
    #pre_warmed_instance_count = 0
    python_version            = "3.4"
    remote_debugging_enabled  = false
    remote_debugging_version  = "VS2019"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = false
    websockets_enabled        = false
    windows_fx_version        = ""
    cors {
      allowed_origins     = []
      support_credentials = false
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER"     = "168.63.129.16"
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL" = "1"
  }
}
```

## **Code for Web App BE**

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "be" {
  location            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  tags                = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.tags

  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.default.id
  name                = module.names-web-app-be.location.app_service.name_unique
  identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }

  auth_settings {
    enabled                       = true
    default_provider              = "AzureActiveDirectory"
    issuer                        = format("https://sts.windows.net/%s/", data.azurerm_client_config.default.tenant_id)
    runtime_version               = "~1"
    token_store_enabled           = true
    unauthenticated_client_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    additional_login_params = {
      "response_type" = "code id_token",
      "resource"      = azuread_application.app-be.application_id
    }
    active_directory {
      client_id         = azuread_application.app-be.object_id
      client_secret     = azuread_application_password.be-app-sp-secret.application_object_id
      allowed_audiences = []
    }
  }

  site_config {
    always_on                 = true
    app_command_line          = ""
    default_documents         = []
    dotnet_framework_version  = "v4.0"
    ftps_state                = "AllAllowed"
    health_check_path         = ""
    http2_enabled             = true
    linux_fx_version          = "DOTNETCORE|3.1"
    local_mysql_enabled       = false
    managed_pipeline_mode     = "Integrated"
    min_tls_version           = "1.2"
    python_version            = "3.4"
    remote_debugging_enabled  = false
    remote_debugging_version  = "VS2019"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = false
    windows_fx_version        = ""
    websockets_enabled        = true
    cors {
      allowed_origins     = [format("https://%s", azurerm_app_service.fe.default_site_hostname)]
      support_credentials = true
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER"     = "168.63.129.16"
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL" = "1"
  }
}
```

## **Code for UUID**

```
resource "random_uuid" "qb2-sal" {}
```

## **Code for FE App Reg**

```
resource "azuread_application" "app-fe" {
  display_name = format("%s-fe", var.project.name)

  api {
    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Allows the app to read and write data"
      admin_consent_display_name = local.oauth2_permissions.read-and-write.admin_consent_display_name
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = random_uuid.qb2-sal.results
      type                       = "User"
      value                      = "read-and-write"
    }
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User", "Application"]
    description          = "Application administrators have the ability to administer the application."
    display_name         = local.app_roles.application-administrator.display_name
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "02c4e591-d667-51db-5597-e2c446ec246b"
    value                = "application-administrator"
  }

  web {
    logout_url    = format("https://%s.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout", module.names-web-app-fe.location.app_service.name_unique)
    redirect_uris = [format("https://%s.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback", module.names-web-app-fe.location.app_service.name_unique)]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = azuread_application.app-be.application_id # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
      id   = "02c4e591-d667-51db-5597-e2c446ec246b" # User.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    }
  }
}
```

## **FE App SP Secret**

```
resource "azuread_application_password" "fe-app-sp-secret" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.app-fe.object_id
}
```

## **BE App Reg**

```
resource "azuread_application" "app-be" {
  display_name = format("%s-be", var.project.name)

  api {
    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Allows the app to read and write data"
      admin_consent_display_name = local.oauth2_permissions.read-and-write.admin_consent_display_name
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = random_uuid.qb2-sal.result
      type                       = "User"
      value                      = "read-and-write"
    }
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User", "Application"]
    description          = "Application administrators have the ability to administer the application."
    display_name         = local.app_roles.application-administrator.display_name
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "02c4e591-d667-51db-5597-e2c446ec246b"
    value                = "application-administrator"
  }

  web {
    logout_url    = format("https://%s.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout", module.names-web-app-be.location.app_service.name_unique)
    redirect_uris = [format("https://%s.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback", module.names-web-app-be.location.app_service.name_unique)]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}
```

## **BE App SP Secret**

```
resource "azuread_application_password" "be-app-sp-secret" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.app-be.object_id
}
```

**Error while doing TF plan**

```
 Error: .group_membership_claims: missing expected [
```

Comment: You could use `terraform graph -draw-cycles` and pipe that to the Graphviz to see where the cycle is coming from. The command would then be `terraform graph -draw-cylcles | dot -Tpdf > cycles.pdf`.

Comment: But in general: your secret depends on the app, and the app requires the secret to finish creating. Usually you don't need to specify `depends_on` as Terraform is pretty good determining order in which things need to be created. So, for example, if the application requires the secret, Terraform will create the secret first and then the app. It's the implicit dependency, unlike `depends_on` which is explicit. At least that is how it looks like to me, I might be wrong.

Comment: I fixed the dependency thing, the issue was on the required_resource_access block.I have modified my main code now. But now i get the error below: Error: .group_membership_claims: missing expected [

Comment: Can you post a bigger chunk of `terraform plan` maybe? I don't really work with Azure so I have no clue where this is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You have resource dependency issues with your code. You probably need to use the terraform graph command `terraform graph -draw-cycles` or draw a dependency graph manually (although it's painful) to understand what's really happening. Check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1005791/705383) for more information.

Looking at your code, it seems that you have:

1. `azurerm_app_service.fe` depends on `azuread_application.app-fe`
2. `azuread_application.app-fe` depends on `azurerm_app_service.be`
3. `azurerm_app_service.be` depends on `azurerm_app_service.fe`

This seems to be where your cycle is. Your FE AppService depends on the BE AppService to be created but the  BE AppService has a dependency on the hostname of the FE AppService.

I believe as a quick fix you could try to remove this line to fix it (although I have not tried it). Or else, re-reference otherwise or even try to add it post deployment.

```
allowed_origins     = [format("https://%s", azurerm_app_service.fe.default_site_hostname)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's now some help in the TF documentation:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/microsoft-graph

Search for "group_membership_claims"